# Java/Spring/MultipartFile File-upload with AngularJS:DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver: MultipartFile param not present" Controller is getting the file

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, file-upload, multipart

> Spring-controller is getting the MultipartFile, but its still throwing

**"DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:186 - Handler execution resulted in exception: Required MultipartFile parameter 'txnFile' is not present"**
This is causing AngularJS client call to fail with 400.

**JAVA-Spring-Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response uploadMultipleFileHandler(
        @RequestParam("fileType") String fileType,
        @RequestParam("fileEtx") String fileEtx,
        @RequestParam("country") String country,
        @RequestParam("network") String network,
        @RequestParam("version") String version,
        @RequestParam("txnDate") String txnDateStr,
        @RequestParam("txnFile") MultipartFile txnFile,
        @RequestParam("exceptionFile") MultipartFile exceptionFile){
    Response response= null;
    try {
```

> Here, txnFile and exceptionFile is not null. Code runs file as well. But it still throws **"DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:186 - Handler execution resulted in exception: Required MultipartFile parameter 'txnFile' is not present"**

**Java-Spring-Config**:
`<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
    </bean>`

**HTML-AngularJS-Form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/recon-validation-tool/ctrl/core/uploadMultipleFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Txn file:</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Txn-file:</label>
            <input type="file" file-model="txnFile"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Exec file:</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Exec file:</label>
            <input type="file" file-model="exceptionFile"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset> 

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please enter carrier details:</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txnDate">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="txnDate" ng-model="formData.txnDate" value="2017-05-30">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fileType">Type:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fileType" ng-model="formData.fileType">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fileEtx">Ext:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fileEtx" ng-model="formData.fileEtx">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">country:</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="formData.country">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">network:</label>
            <input type="text" name="network" ng-model="formData.network">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="version">version:</label>
            <input type="text" name="version" ng-model="formData.version">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Validate</button>
</form>
```

**AngularJS-Controller:**

```
controllerM.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope){
$scope.formData= {};
$scope.formData.fileEtx= "";
$scope.formData.fileType= "";
$scope.formData.country= "";
$scope.formData.network= "";
$scope.formData.version= "";
$scope.formData.txnDate= "";

$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('fileEtx', $scope.formData.fileEtx);
    data.append('fileType', $scope.formData.fileType);
    data.append('country', $scope.formData.country);
    data.append('network', $scope.formData.network);
    data.append('version', $scope.formData.version);
    data.append('txnDate', $scope.formData.txnDate);
    data.append('txnFile', $scope.txnFile);
    data.append('exceptionFile', $scope.exceptionFile);

    var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:8080/recon-validation-tool/ctrl/core/uploadMultipleFile";

    $http.post(uploadUrl, data, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
    .success(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    })
    .error(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    });
};
```

});

Comment: are you getting data server in server side.@RequestMapping(value = "/addRsoData",consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public Produce produceData(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile[] files,
   @RequestPart("produce")Produce produce,
   HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: instead of @RequestParam use @RequestPart("file")

Comment: Yes. I am getting all data in Server side. Still getting the error.

Comment: you get only one file right

Comment: Replaced @RequestParam("txnFile") with @RequestPart("txnFile"). Same problem. And I am getting both the files i.e. txnFile and exceptionFile.

Comment: once you print both file names file name in console. txnFile is not available

Comment: String fileName; if (txnFile != null && txnFile.length >0) {
  for(int i =0 ;i< txnFile.length; i++){
            try {
                fileName = txnFile[i].getOriginalFilename();
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

Comment: I dont understand that. I am able access and everything :) Seems the problem is, I need to manually make "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver" ignore this warning. That should also remove http-error 400.

Comment: first you check whether the file is reaching the controller by printing the file name using above code.

Comment: File is reaching and I am able to do all processing with it. But, befor controller execution completes, client gets 400 errorcode.

Comment: once check this link : https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-a-400-bad-request-error-2617988